# how to insert a SQL query in to a SQL column as a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble with this Insert function, when one of my value is another query

```
INSERT INTO query_timing (executedTime, query)
VALUES ('2016-11-20 13:08:13.512336', 'SELECT title FROM paper WHERE title ILIKE '%database%';');
```

Error:

> column "database" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ELECT panum, title FROM paper WHERE title ILIKE '%database%'...

Thank you so much

Comment: Your quotation marks are not balanced.

Comment: probably you need `" "` around `database` in SQL because now it treats `database` as column name, not word.

Comment: @KlausD., Please give this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @furas, this won't work

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: I have tried to replace with double quote already but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your quote around the `%database%` is casing the error. Escape the quote by using `''%database%''` instead of `'%database%'`..

Comment: I have tried to replace with double quote already but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Can you put three 3 quotes before and after %database% like this :

```
'''%database%'''
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: 'SELECT title FROM paper WHERE title ILIKE '%database%';'

Comment: Oups! Sorry..   Can you try with this 'SELECT title FROM paper WHERE title ILIKE ' || chr(39)||'%database%'||chr(39)||';'   Where chr(39)= '

Comment: See @AkashChandra answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I got the answer from Mohamad, but his correct answer is posted in comments then I put it here for convenient.
Just replace ' with '||chr(39)||' since chr(39) is the '